# Rookie question - Can I write a script that executes actions for our internal cloud software?

Tags: java, python

I work for a big global company (100 000 employees) and we have an internal software (its a database), this service/softwareh can be accessed from all employes via their internet browsers.

I need to change about 200 names in this databas and it is a VERY repetative work which takes time due to the cloud service is sometimes very slow. It usually takes 20 minutes to change one name... and I need to do 200 names!!

I have asked if its possible to just write a script that picks up my information from an excel sheet, then open ups the internet explorer, go to the site, click on all the correct buttons and paste the correct values.

The answer I got was "It is not possible to write a script to alter the database, you would need to go via IT department and via the correct programmers". But I assume that is if I want to superbig mass-update the database? I just want to get rid of the repetative task so I dont need to sit and wait 20 minutes x 200 names.

I guess my question is: Is it possible to write a script that performs actions via internet explorer EVEN IF ITS AN INTERNAL SOFTWARE/CLOUD SERVICE we are visiting?

Please - Im very very new to coding, as you might tell.

Comment: Almost anything's technically possible, but your actual question is whether it's possible for *you* isn't it? If it takes you 4000 minutes to change those names manually, you'll be done faster than you've learned to program. However mouse and keyboard has been automated for decades if you just want to robotize your work. Look at autohotkey for example.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow! It's definitely possible to automate those sorts of tasks using scripts, but if you're going down that route I would suggest that automating via internet explorer isn't the best option. Perhaps your IT team could look into creating a tool to access and modify the database directly instead? That would likely be much faster and less convoluted to set up than automating via a web interface.

However, if you're set on using a web browser to automate tasks I would suggest that you start by looking into basic javaScript tutorials and jquery to get started with web manipulation (jquery is an addon library for javascript that lets you set up interactions with web page elements in a friendlier way)! Using javascript you can write scripts to simulate button clicks and enter text values, which sounds like what you're looking for.